# How to Change Router Load Order

Tags: controllers, magento-1, router

I have a custom router that I'd like to be used for matching before the Standard router. I'm having issues trying to figure out how to change the order in which the routers are added and used for matching requests subsequently.

It looks like the `Admin` and `Standard` routers are defined in `Mage_Core`'s `config.xml` and loaded in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::init` with following line.

```
$routersInfo = Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_STORE_ROUTERS_PATH);
```

However, I've tried to add my custom router's definition in `Mage_Core`'s `config.xml` before any of the default routers to test, but it still gets added at the end. I've tried changing the order in which `Admin` and `Standard` routers are defined in `config.xml`, and that doesn't take effect. I clear cache, and I'm not sure why.

I wan to do this without rewriting `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard` (`app/code/local/Mage/Core/...`), if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to make the `Mage_Core` module depend on your module?

Comment: Yeah, I did. The problem was that I made a mistake of modifying the `config/default/web/routers` in `config.xml`, instead of the `config/stores/default/web/routers` node that `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front` uses to add the routers. It seems like I can load mine first now. I didn't realize there was a `config/*stores*/...` node.

Comment: @Marius, router load order can be changed when modifying `Mage/Core/etc/config.xml`, but it doesn't seem possible from a local extension. The only way for me is to comment out `config/stores/...` note entirely in `Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` and redefine it in the order I want in my extension. Any idea how to do this without modifying core? For now, I just overrode the entire Standard router to skip matching for a certain request.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load your custom router prior to all other routers in Magento, then try this one.

### Define your custom router in `config.xml`

File : `app\code\{codePool}\{Namespace}\{Module}\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <default>
        <web>
            <routers>
                <{router_identifier}>
                    <area>{admin|frontend}</area>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Controller_Router</class>
                </{router_identifier}>
            </routers>
        </web>
    </default>
    <stores>
        <default>
            <web>
                <routers>
                    <{router_identifier}>
                        <area>{admin|frontend}</area>
                        <class>Namespace_Module_Controller_Router</class>
                    </{router_identifier}>
                </routers>
            </web>
        </default>
    </stores>
</config>
```

### Now make `core` module depend on your module

File : `app\etc\modules\Namespace_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>{local|community}</codePool>
        </Namespace_Module>
        <Mage_Core>
            <depends>
                <Namespace_Module />
            </depends>
        </Mage_Core>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now clear your cache. You are done.

### Why does This work

Router loading is happening inside *front-controller*<sup>**1**</sup>. The abbreviated form of router loading code is shown below.

```
public function init()
{

    //prioriy 1 : routers adding via xml configuration
    $routersInfo = Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_STORE_ROUTERS_PATH);
    foreach ($routersInfo as $routerCode => $routerInfo) {
        if (isset($routerInfo['disabled']) && $routerInfo['disabled']) {
            continue;
        }
        if (isset($routerInfo['class'])) {
            $router = new $routerInfo['class'];
            if (isset($routerInfo['area'])) {
                $router->collectRoutes($routerInfo['area'], $routerCode);
            }
            $this->addRouter($routerCode, $router);
        }
    }

    //priority 2: routers adding via observer
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_front_init_routers', array('front'=>$this));

    // pririry 3 : for default router.
    $default = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Default();
    $this->addRouter('default', $default);

    return $this;
}
```

This method simply grabs routers from various resources and add it to the protected property `$_routers` as an array<sup>**2**</sup>. As you can see, the priorities are like this:

1. Routers which are defined via XML files will be added to `$_routers` first
2. Routers which are added via the event `controller_front_init_routers` go next
3. At last, the Default router will be added to the array

Now, the *standard* router and *admin* router are defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` and hence they will be loaded first in the `$_routers` array and thus they will be processed first.

In order to change this intentional priority for the standard and admin router, you need to define your router via your module's `config.xml` file. This will bring your router to the priority level 1. Making core module depend on your module gives more priority to your module and hence Magento will consider your module first and hence load your router in `$_routers` array first.

Hope that makes sense.

---

<sup>1: `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::init()`</sup>

<sup>2: `$this->addRouter()` is actually what populates `$_routers`.</sup>

Comment: I'm very curious how such a thing would be possible if you wouldn't edit core files. A solution that involves editing core files while it would not be necessary, is not a good solution in my opinion.

Comment: @7ochem the solution that i provided should work in theory. See the "Why does this work" section. I explained with code why it works there. In my analysis, my method should work without touching any core files in theory. I didnt try this before. I will try my method once I get some free time and update this answer accordingly

Comment: Sorry I've misread your code example. You're adding the dependency inside the custom module's `config.xml`. Well, then I understand your doubt whether this will work. If I look at the dependency code, then I think this should work, setting a dependency of a core module in a custom module's `config.xml`

Comment: @7ochem I smelled that mis-read :)

Comment: Hm I just saw this. I'll try this out when I get the chance in a week or two and report back.

Comment: @musicfitsme you should :thumbs_up

Comment: @musicliftsme hello, did you try this ? any updates ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change router load order is through **controller_front_init_before** event because **is invoked right before any router gets added**.

so in `app\code\{codePool}\{Namespace}\{Module}\etc\config.xml`
add a listener for that event:

```
<controller_front_init_before>
  <observers>
    <Namespace_Module>
      <class>Namespace_Module_Controller_Router</class>
      <method>initControllerRouters</method>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </observers>
</controller_front_init_before>
```

(I've used the same Router Class so $this object represents the router)

Then in `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Controller/Router.php`

```
public function initControllerRouters(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
  $front->addRouter('Namespace_Module', $this);
}
```

(change $this object for your router in case your event class is in Model/Observer or somewhere else than the router class itself)